# Find the topologies of sets of at most four elements

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

**Problem**

Find all the topologies of the sets with at most four elements.

**The attempt at a solution**

I've tried to divide the problem into five cases according to the cardinal of the set

I know that if $\tau$ is a topology defined on a set $X$, then the following conditions must be satisfied:

i) $X,\emptyset \in \tau$.

ii) Any arbitrary union of elements of $\tau$ is in $\tau$.

iii) Any arbitrary finite intersection of elements in $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$.

Case 1: $X=\emptyset$, then $\tau=\{X\}$ is the only possible topology.

Case 2:$|X|=1$, suppose $X={a}$, then, as $X,\emptyset$ have to be in $\tau$, the only possible topology is $\tau=\{\emptyset,X\}$

Case 3: $|X|=2$, suppose $X=\{a,b\}$. We have the trivial topology $\tau=\{\emptyset,X\}$. If $\tau=\{\emptyset,X,\{e\}\}$ for some $e \in \{a,b\}$, then it is easy to check that unions and finite intersections remain in $\tau$, so $\tau$ is also a topology. The same goes for $\tau=\{\emptyset,X,\{a\},\{b\}\}$ These are the only topologies for a set of two elements.

Case 4: $|X|=3$. Here things get a little more tedious to write. I've checked that $\tau_1=\{\emptyset,X\};\tau_2=\{\emptyset,X,\{e\}\} : e \in \{a,b,c\}; \tau_3=\{\emptyset,X,\{e_1,e_2\}\} : e_1,e_2 \in \{a,b,c\};\tau_4=\{\emptyset,X,\{e_1,e_2\},\{e_i\}\} : e_i \in \{e_1,e_2\}$ are all topologies.

My problem is: how can I keep account of all the collections of subsets of $X$ in a clear and organized way so to check if each collection satisfies the axioms?

Comment: Tedious and careful bookkeeping. These sort of "filler" questions are the worst. But sometimes you just have to give them. :-\

Comment: Yes, I hate these type of questions. But I don't know how to keep track of all the collections I must consider. Say $|X|=3$, then I must consider all possible collections of $\mathcal P(X)$ and study them. Is there any way, using for example combinatory tools to count all possible collections of $\mathcal P(X)$ which contain $X$ and $\emptyset$? (since $X$ and $\emptyset$ must also be in $\tau$). I hope my question is clear.

Comment: I don't know any general algorithm which is not going over all the collections. Something to consider, order your collections lexicographically.

Answer (score 4):

See [OEIS sequence A000798](https://oeis.org/A000798) and references given there.